# $L^1$ and $L^2$ norms inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded measurable function with respect to the Lesbegue measure satisfying $\|f\|_2 = \left\{\int_0^\infty f^2(x)dx\right\}^{1/2}<\infty$.
Is there any known condition of $f$ for $\|f\|_1 = \int_0^\infty |f(x)|dx < \infty$?
In other words, is there any condition of $f$ such that if $\|f\|_2<\infty$, then there exists $M_f<\infty$ that depends on $f$ such that $\|f\|_1 \le M_f\|f\|_2$?

---

**Edit**

Probably, it would be better to give an example I am working on.
Let $\delta>0$.
Then, by the Schwarz inequality
\begin{equation*}
\|f\|_1 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{n\delta}^{(n+1)\delta}|f(x)|dx \le \sqrt{\delta}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left\{\int_{n\delta}^{(n+1)\delta}f^2(x)dx\right\}^{1/2}.
\end{equation*} 
The series on the right converges if 
\begin{equation*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\{ \int_{n\delta}^{(n+1)\delta}f^2(x)dx\right\}^{1/n} < 1
\end{equation*}
or
\begin{equation*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_{(n+1)\delta}^{(n+2)\delta}f^2(x)dx}{\int_{n\delta}^{(n+1)\delta}f^2(x)dx}<1.
\end{equation*}
Thus, if the convergent series
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{n\delta}^{(n+1)\delta}f^2(x)dx = \|f\|_2^2 <\infty
\end{equation*}
satisfies one of those conditions, then $\|f\|_1<\infty$.

I hope that this example is correct. By the way, the conditions I found above are not easy to work with for my original problem. So, I am wondering if there are some other conditions.

Comment: You are asking "when does an $L^2$ function become an $L^1$ function?" Am I correct?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes, exactly.

Comment: You might want to write if there exists an $M_f$ such that $||f||_1\leq M_f ||f||_2$..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik corrected. Thanks.

Comment: coming to the question, I do not know what condition I should put on an element of $L^2$ to become an element of $L^1$..

Answer (score 2):

**remark**
A condition is certainly needed.  $\|f\|_1 \le M\|f\|_2
$ fails for some $f$.

Indeed, you can find examples where $\|f\|_1 = \infty$ and $\|f\|_2 < \infty$.  Using these you can make sequences $f_n \in L_1 \cap L_2$ where $\|f_n\|_1 \to\infty$ but $\|f_n\|_2$ remains bounded.

For such example, try either $f(x) = x^a$ on $(0,1]$ for some $a$ or else $f(x) = x^a$ on $[1,\infty)$ for some $a$.  One of these will be your counterexample, the other will be a counterexample to $\|f\|_2 \le M \|f\|_1$.

Comment: I do not understand the answer... OP is asking, given a function $f$, knowning that it is in $L^2$, can I put an other condition on it so that it belongs to $L^1$.. You have given functions $f$ such that $f\in L^2\setminus L^1$..